# Several Windows 7 Jump List items lost, How to get them back?

Tags: windows-7, jumplist

I'm using Windows 7 for quite some time, on several systems. On 2 of these systems, Jumplist Items tend to disappear.

Example:
Initially, I was able to see recently openend folders in Windows Explorer, as well as pinned folders. Then, these functions disappear, all that's left is the "Windows Explorer", "Unpin..." and "Close all windows"-options, all others are gone.

Theoretically, a new profile WOULD work. I made a new profile, the new profile had the correct jump lists again, but I don't want to create a new profile, there is too much I would have to do to make it work. Is there an alternative to get the the jumplists back? A reset of sorts, or something different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to these articles it is caused by file corruption, no way to get old jump lists back, but you can restore it to work for new items.

http://www.mydigitallife.info/2010/07/04/fix-windows-7-jump-lists-missing-or-does-not-display-recent-items-or-pinned-files/

and this
http://www.shadowsplace.net/general/windows/windows-7-jump-lists-troubleshooting-missing-items/

I guess one could periodically back up this file.

Comment: I wasn't actually trying to get the pinned items or jump list history back, so removing those corrupted entries seems to be the perfect solution. Thanks a lot

Comment: this is like the third time this has happened to me. I'm a jumplist junky and they seem to disappear every few months. I ended up setting up a schedule task to copy these files into a backup folder every week so I can roll back. Maybe they fixed it in Win 8?